# CSOM Updating List Item in Large List throws Threshold Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, list-view-threshold

**Background:**

- Have a large document library (25K+ Documents) in a SharePoint Online
  Website.
- We migrated this Document Library from SharePoint 2013.
- This library has a few MetaData Lookup columns that we setup the Term Set in SPOnline to be 1-1 to what SP2013 was. **These Columns are Indexed.**

**The Issue:**

Not all MetaData column values migrated over successfully. We need to Update these values in order for the search functionality to work.

**What we can do:**

- CamlQuery is setup to create a List of ListItems from paging 5000 rows at a time. (Pushes past the 5000 Item Threshold)
- We can load the Term Set to grab the correct Guids to set the ListItem["MetaData"] column

**What we can't do:**

- When running the update ListItem.Update method we get a server side exception

> "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldValueException: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."

```
List <ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
do
{
     ListItemCollection listItemCollection = docLib.GetItems(camlQuery);
     client.Load(listItemCollection, i => i.Include(x => x["ID"], x => x["Project"]), i => i.ListItemCollectionPosition);

     client.ExecuteQuery();
     
     items.AddRange(listItemCollection);

     //Reset the current pagination info
     pStart = pEnd;
     pEnd = pEnd + rowLimit;
     camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = listItemCollection.ListItemCollectionPosition;
} while (camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition != null); 

foreach (var item in items)
{
     item["Project"] = termItem.Id.ToString();
     item.Update();
     client.ExecuteQuery(); //Throws Error on Execute

     //Also Tried Below, same error
     //item.ParseAndSetFieldValue("Project", termItem.Id.ToString());
     //client.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Not sure if anyone knows how to push past the Threshold Error when updating a column value on a large list. The CamlQuery is currently filtering out 1 item to test. Below is an example of the current query used.

```
<List Scope='RecursiveAll'>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
    <FieldRef Name="Project" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="ID" />
    </OrderBy>
    <Where>
      <And>
        <And>
          <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
            <Value id="start" Type="Counter">0</Value>
          </Geq>
          <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
            <Value id="end" Type="Counter">5</Value>
          </Lt>
        </And>
        <IsNull>
          <FieldRef Name="Project" />
        </IsNull>
      </And>
    </Where>
  </Query>
  <RowLimit id="rowlimit" Paged='TRUE'>5000</RowLimit>
</List>
```

*Update* - Issue seems to just be with the MetaData Column type. I created a brand new Document Library with two items and manually tried to enter MetaData Values within the Test Columns and SharePoint Online still throws a Threshold Error. The MetaData Term store I tested with has 5 terms associated with it and it still threw a threshold error. Makes no sense.

Created a regular Text column and can update fine. This technically should work but I can only assume something is wrong with the SP Online. Hopefully this will solve some others headaches for now until this is (maybe) fixed in the future.